# Spring Data JPA: Row lost from result when null appears in sort column

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

I am trying to get data from the Spring Data JPA repository which throws JPQL with sort column. This column corresponds to fields with the `OneToMany` annotation.
In any value that has null in that field does not exist in the result.
This behaviour exists only when data requests to throw JPQL. If I construct the same query throw, Specification, and call `repository.findAll(specification, paggeble)`, everything works fine.

In this post, [Spring-data JPA repository Order by losing null values in results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052843/spring-data-jpa-repository-order-by-losing-null-values-in-results), it says that the bug fix is in Spring Data starting from version 1.2.1. But I tried on version 1.11.13 and the bug is still there.

Piece of code for better understanding:

```
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<MyEntity> {

    @Query(value =
        "SELECT e "
        + "  FROM MyEntity e "
        + "  WHERE e.flg = :flg "
        + "";)
    Page<MyEntity> findByFlg(
        Pageable pageable
    );
}

public class Service {

    //This method return full result. 
    //If field dept.someField is null MyEntity obj still exists in page
    public Page<MyEntity> findDataSpec(Pageable pageable) { //sort[dept.someField:ASC]
        Specification<MyEntity> specification = (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            Path flg = root.get("flg");
            return criteriaBuilder.equal(flg, "1");
        };
        Page<MyEntity> page = myEntityRepository.findByDeptAndTpAndKnd(specification, pageable);
        return page;
    }

    //This method return wrong result. 
    //If field dept.someField is null MyEntity obj escape from page
    public Page<MyEntity> findDataJpql(Pageable pageable) {//sort[dept.someField:ASC]
        Page<MyEntity> page = myEntityRepository.findByFlg("1", pageable);
        return page;
    }
}
```

May someone explain why two identical queries work so different and which of these work wrong.
What I need to do for JPQL query is have the same behavior like specification behavior.

Comment: Can you provide the source code of your entities?